# Load external image urls

Tags: product-images, import, magento2.4.4, external-images

I would like to know if it's possible to import image as links when adding products to catalogs. I currently have an API setup that takes the individual images links them to the products and then upload and retrieves the link to the image hosted on cloud flare images. I do not want Magento to make a copy of the image because we have limited bandwidth in the office and I would like cloud flare to host the images because it makes it easier to delete images when products get removed from the site.

Comment: What version of Magento are you working with?

Comment: I’m working with version 2.4.4. I’ve been using the import menu to add my images but it’s trying to download them from the url and I only want it to link the product image to the remote url